# How would I make a Discord reaction role STAY ALIVE when the bot reboots?

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I am using quick.db and the discord-reaction-roles package. How would I go about doing this? The quick.db saves the data as JSON in a `json.sqlite` file. Would I do something when `client.on('ready')` it fetches data from the json file and creates the reaction roles or what?

Comment: You can save the ID of the message as persistent, fetch it (you will have to deal with it being uncached), and then re-add the listener

Comment: The problem with that is JSON.parse is acting up and won't convert the JSON into an array, so I can't re-add the listener (I don't have the listener data).